# Monitoring resource usage of cronjob in Google Container Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

In order to specify the resource limits for a [cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) in GKE, I need to monitor how much CPU and memory cronjob utilizes. All the resources on monitoring are either pod level or node level. I have already enabled Stackdriver monitoring for the cluster.